# Read from a text file in Matlab and form a 2D contour plot

Tags: matlab, text, plot, contour

I have three columns of data, with n number of rows in a text file, I want to read the data want to plot a contour plot.

```
x   y  z   
1  2  3
2  3  4
5  5  5
4  4  5
```

As shown above I have three columns of data `x, y, z`. Now I want to read each `x`, `y`, `z` data and plot in a contour plot.

What i have managed to do is

```
[gnd, x, y] = textread('abc.txt', '%n,%n,%n');
contourf(x,y,gnd)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this (version of your) question.  I suggest that you wait for answers to the other version (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660694/carry-out-the-operation-in-matlab) before complicating your life by trying to make a contour plot.

Comment: So I ask again: what have you tried ?  Again, SO is here to help, not do your work for you.

Comment: Right, so I've just called up the documentation for `textread` (type `textread` at the Matlab command line and hit F1 if you haven't figured this out yet).  Right away the help (a) tells me that `textread` is deprecated (I'm on R2011b), and (b) offers alternatives, including the Import Wizard.  For a beginner such as yourself I strongly suggest becoming familiar with the Import Wizard, you can study the more sophisticated alternatives later. Finally,  Matlab is interactive and very powerful, start experimenting and teaching yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reading this should work:

```
fid = fopen('abc.txt');
fgets(fid); % to get rid of the first line of characters ("x y z")
A = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f');
x = A{1};
y = A{2};
z = A{3};
```

But the data seems not to be very structured. So maybe `scatter(x,y,5,z)` might be the better plotting option?